# Setting up smtp for sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api

Ok so I am tasked with setting up a submit action class to send an email. I setup everything like below and it gets all the way through till the send email and then throws an error

"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed"

I did some research and it says I need to use port 587 which I am as you can see below. However I havent added anything to the webconfig or the sitecore.config to set SMTP up. Is there something else needed before an email can be sent?

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("mjones@myemail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("mjones@myemail.com");
        mail.Subject = "We hit the code";
        string Body = "Nothing in the body as of yet!";
        mail.Body = Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried going through this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228644/smtpexception-unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-net-io-connect ? There is also a way to set up credentials in sitecore configs as mentioned in here https://www.jondjones.com/learn-sitecore-cms/sitecore-developers-guide/how-to-configure-sitecore/how-to-configure-smtp-details-in-sitecore/ but as far as i know this will be more related to password recovery etc.

Comment: Seems like the second issue is more with marketing emails which this is not doing. I am trying to setup a custom email from a form submit action

Answer (score 2):

Create a patch config and add the following setting and update the values

```
 <!--  MAIL SERVER
SMTP server used for sending mails by the Sitecore server
Is used by MainUtil.SendMail()
Default value: ""
-->
<setting name="MailServer" value="#{MailServer}#" patch:instead="setting[@name='MailServer']"/>

<!--  MAIL SERVER PORT
If the SMTP server requires a custom port number, enter the value in this setting.
The default value is: 25
-->
<setting name="MailServerPort" value="#{MailServerPort}#" patch:instead="setting[@name='MailServerPort']"/>

<!--  MAIL SERVER USER
If the SMTP server requires login, enter the user name in this setting
-->
<setting name="MailServerUserName" value="#{MailServerUserName}#" patch:instead="setting[@name='MailServerUserName']"/>
<setting name="MailServerPassword" value="#{MailServerPassword}#" patch:instead="setting[@name='MailServerPassword']"/>
```

once you set this patch config, do the following in your send email method

```
var mailMessage = new MailMessage
    {
        From = new MailAddress(fromEmail),
        Subject = "Subject",
        Body = message,
        IsBodyHtml = isHtml
    };
    
MainUtil.SendMail(mailMessage);
```

MailUtil is a library by Sitecore which uses the config settings to send email. you can use this method in your end email action.

by using the MainUtil, you can remove the code

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Hope this helps.